# How to draw Convex Rectangle in combination with ellipsoids by using Qt4.8 (C++)? (top view of a boat)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qpolygon, qpainterpath

I'm currently trying to draw the top view of a boat by using Qt 4.8 (C++).
I want to implement a QWidget in which a boat moves around.

Therefore I need to draw the top view of a boat, it should look similiar to this (only need the outer boarders):

[image: example of boat]
<sub>(source: [4vector.com](http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-japanese-map-symbol-car-ferry-clip-art_121378_japanese-map-symbol-car-ferry-clip-art/Japanese_Map_Symbol_Car_Ferry_clip_art_medium.png))</sub>

Currently I'm experimenting with QPainter in combination with QPainterPath but I can't figure out how to combine the ellipsoids and rectangles correctly. Another option would be to draw it as an polygon but I would need a lot of points to let it look good.

Besides I think a solution by using only a rectangle and two ellipsoids or simliar solutions would be more beautiful.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you need to draw it with QPainter instead of drawing/loading a pixmap and move it around?

Comment: I would prefer using the QPainter tool to reach more flexibility.

Comment: Flexibility? In which sense? You might simply load an image posted above in your question and use it as your painting instead of drawing complex curves.

Comment: Flexibility in the sense of that I am able to transform the boats shape, fill and color at runtime.

Comment: I would go with @vahancho input If you are talking about a finite number of shapes. Still if you want to go with QPainter use `QPainterPath::cubicTo` and subtract from rectangles using `QPainterPath::subtracted`

Comment: @vahancho Using a pixmap is always a bit problematic for geometric shapes (zooming, rotation, scaling, overlapping other shapes...), because pixmap consists of pixels.

Comment: Philipp, what exactly is the problem you ate having with your painter code? It's hard to tell how to fix the code when you don't show the code.

Comment: I would start with boat made of 5 straight lines. Then once that works, change the two nose lines to be Bezier curves (read the doc!).